# Converting string to integer - SharedPreferences

Tags: android

My first Class:

```
     public SharedPreferences abc;
     abc = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Trening",0);
```

My second Class(extends first class):

```
    Integer i = Integer.parseInt(abc.getString("T1","0"));
```

The Error is:

```
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.String android.content.SharedPreferences.getString(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

I learn to program for 3 days and hope you can help me and explain how to fix it, so I can learn.

Sorry for my english. :)

Comment: Why are you using getString on an object that is already a string?  What it's trying to do is get the string from whatever is named "T1", which is probably nothing (NULL).

Comment: T1 is a name of an saved value.

Answer (score 0):

You should just convert the value you already have:

```
Integer i = Integer.parseInt(abc);
```

There is no need to getString, since you've already populated that with either what it finds in the SharedPreference or the default 0.

Comment: It's probably because you have abc declared as "Shared Preferences".  It should just be String.